# python spyder - debug only current cell or selection?

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

Similarly to these (very useful!) two functions:

"Run current cell"
"Run selection or current line"

Is it possible to do this with debugging? I dont want to start from the top of my large script files every time I debug.

I'm using Spyder version 3.2.4

Comment: You can place breakpoints in your script, with F12. You can place a breakpoint at the point you want your debugger to start, and then run the script?

Comment: How do I place a breakpoint that tells the debugger to "start there"? If i place two breakpoints it will still start from the beginning of my file. The breakpoints are just for "jumping" to the next one (it still needs to run all the code in between, which is what I want to skip)

Comment: Ok. I was a little unclear on what you wanted, then.

Comment: Definitely a missing feature IMHO

Answer (score 3):

If you are using IPython as your interpreter, you can use the magic `%pdb` in IPython to automatically start `pdb` when an error is encountered.

Then you can "Run current cell" and break out into the debugger when you need to.

For example I have a simple script:

```
my_var = 4
raise ValueError
```

Now, in the IPython terminal I first run `%pdb`, and then I run my script.

```
In [4]: my_var = 4
   ...: raise ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-31dc119cb1f3>", line 2, in <module>
    raise ValueError

ValueError

> <ipython-input-4-31dc119cb1f3>(2)<module>()
      1 my_var = 4
----> 2 raise ValueError


ipdb>
```

and I have the debugger available.

Comment: I tried that. I write %pdb and it says "Automatic pdb calling has been turned ON". However when I run my cell the debugger doesnt start. It should go into "one line at a time" mode right? If I run the current cell it just runs it normally (no debugger) if i press start debug it starts from the top of the file.

Comment: It only goes into the debugger when it encounters and error. You can just add "raise" in your source code if you want it to start the debugger at at that point

Comment: I tried that, it now says "RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise" and exists debug mode and continues with a normal execution of the code...

Comment: Try `raise ValueError`. The `raise` statement needs an exception.

Comment: @KPLauritzen, I think the right magic is `%debug`, not `%pdb`. A call to `pdb.set_trace()` could do the job too.

Comment: running "raise ValueError" in my code just causes "valueError" and stops the execution for me.

How is %debug supposed to work? It doesnt do anything useful when I try it.  

Calling pdb.set_prace() does seem to start the debugger when excecution reaches that line, but when i try to step through the lines (debug them) it then jumps to debugging "interactiveshell.py" instead, which is not useful to me.

Comment: No input in this issue? It is very inconvinient to be forced to run the entire script every time I debug. I need to work with large python script for my work and debugging a cell or selection seems like a basic feature.

Comment: This answer is very useful. But is there a way to debug only a cell? Sometimes you don't have an interpreter error, sometimes do you have wrong return value. And in that case you will want to run the debug until a breakpoint and run line by line from there

Answer (score 3):

Now you have Debug -> Debug Cell option. Or Alt+Shift+Return

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pdb command [`j(ump)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-jump) to get to the right line.

e.g.

```
debugfile()
jump 100
```

brings the debugger to line 100 of your script (or a few lines later if line 100 is not executable). From there you can continue as usual.

Answer (score 0):

### More details about the debug cell solution:

First you need to split your code into cells using the #%% separator, then you can either choose to run or debug a cell. In the example below you run the first cell then debug the second cell:

```
#%% SOME TIME CONSUMING CODE TO EXECUTE
...
...
#%% CODE TO DEBUG
...
```